# Lambda function cant load AWS sdk after switching to 18.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I upgraded my Lambda function from node12.x to node18.x

The code worked perfectly fine on 12.x, after switching to 18.x, I can no longer include the AWS sdk:

I used to include it by simply typing:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

I now get this error

```
"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
```

I think if I can just get the AWS sdk to load properly the function should be fine, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I switched to node 16.x and now it works.  Probably just going to stick with this now as I don't feel like dealing with this headache right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the aws-sdk in your lambda's package.json file.

```
npm install aws-sdk@2
```

Comment: i randomly came back to this problem after a year.  I ended up bootstrapping the sdk v2 to my function like this.  takes a bit longer to upload but works more consistent and now i can use node 18+
I still had to convert my code a little bit too but wasn't a big deal

Answer (score 17):

The [Node.js 18 Lambda runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html) is preloaded with the [AWS SDK for JS v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html).

The earlier runtimes have the [SDK v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html).

Of course you can still use the SDK v2 with the Node.js 18 runtime.  You just need to package the clients as dependencies with your Lambda code.

---

The v2 SDK's `aws-sdk` package (preloaded on the 14.x, 16.x Lambda Node.js runtimes) contains every client.  The v3 service clients (preloaded on 18.x) are [modularised](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html#modularized-packages) in separate `@aws-sdk/client-[something]` packages.  Here's a v3 sample import for getting an S3 object:

```js
// v3
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
```

See the [Getting Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html#getting-started) guide in the SDK v3 docs.

Comment: thanks, gonna stick with 16.x for now

Comment: I used the following within nodejs 18.x:
`
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
`
which also throws   "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'aws-sdk'  imported from /var/task/index.mjs"

Can I get pls get help on a fix for this, instead of moving to node 16.x

Comment: @PeeKay `aws-sdk` is the SDK v2 package. It is not preloaded in 18.x  The v3 packages are.

Comment: so what is the proper syntax for V3 package import?

Comment: @kravb I added a v3 import example.

Comment: There are many packages not available in node JS 18 runtime for lambda. Some of them are:
@aws-crypto/sha256-browser
@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider
@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager

Is there any link which provides full list of available package in runtime?